# How to write a large CSV file to SFTP in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to write a large CSV file to SFTP.
Used For each to split the records and write using SFTP connector.
But the file is not reaching the SFTP.
What am I doing wrong here?

Below is the flow:

```
<flow name="sftp-Flow" doc:id="294e7265-0bb3-466b-add4-5819088bd33c">
<file:listener doc:name="File picked from path" directory="${processing.folder}" config-ref="File-Inbound" autoDelete="true" matcher="filename-regex-filter" doc:id="bbfb12df-96a4-443f-a137-ef90c74e7de1" outputMimeType="application/csv" primaryNodeOnly="true" timeBetweenSizeCheck="1" timeBetweenSizeCheckUnit="SECONDS">
    <repeatable-in-memory-stream initialBufferSize="1" bufferSizeIncrement="1" maxBufferSize="500" bufferUnit="MB"/>
    <scheduling-strategy>
        <fixed-frequency frequency="${file.connector.polling.frequency}"/>
    </scheduling-strategy>
</file:listener>

<set-variable value="#[attributes.fileName]" doc:name="fileName - Variable" doc:id="5f064507-be62-4484-86ea-62d6cfb547fc" variableName="fileName"/>

<foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="87b79f6d-1321-4231-bc6d-cffbb859d94b" batchSize="500" collection="#[payload]">     
    <sftp:write doc:name="Push file to SFTP" doc:id="d1562478-5276-4a6f-a7fa-4a912bb44b8c" config-ref="SFTP-Connector" path='#["${sftp.remote.folder}" ++ "/" ++ vars.fileName]' mode="APPEND">
        <reconnect frequency="${destination.sftp.connection.retries.delay}" count="${destination.sftp.connection.retries}"/>
    </sftp:write> 
</foreach>

<error-handler ref="catch-exception-strategy"/>
```

Comment: The collection attribute is not an expression. It should be "#[payload]"

Comment: Are you having any error messages?

Comment: Seems a typo, I have corrected the code. However there's no error in the Anypoint Studio console. The flow completes and there's no file on the SFTP. I have verified by logging a message after the for each. Also without the For each a smaller csv file is saved properly on the SFTP.

Comment: what's the need to write the output line by line?

Comment: The CSV file we are receiving is large around 250 MB. This causes OOM in the system. So I am trying to send the file in chunks of data so that the system doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the payload in rexords try setting the CSV reader to [streaming mode](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-csv#reader-properties).

`outputMimeType="application/csv; streaming=true"`

**Update**: the best solution might just to remove both the foreach and the outputMimeType attribute from the File listener. The file will be read and write as a binary using streaming to the SFTP write operation. Remove outputMimeType will prevent Mule from trying to parse the big file as CSV, which is not really needed since the only processing the flow is doing as a CSV is the foreach, which will no longer be needed. This method will be faster and consume less resources.

Comment: Thanks @aled, I think the streaming is already enabled by <repeatable-in-memory-stream initialBufferSize="1" bufferSizeIncrement="1" maxBufferSize="500" bufferUnit="MB"/>

Comment: Actually that's a different kind of streaming. That is what the File connector uses to send the data to the next component. The reader property is to make the DataWeave CSV parser use streaming internally to read the data and not try to parse it all in memory. Having said that I think after reading your other comment I think there may be an even better answer. I'll update my answer later.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The `foreach` directive only supports collections in JSON, XML, or JSON formats. I just placed a transformer to convert the CSV to JSON before the `foreach`. Now the file is properly saved in batches.